# How to solve this Recurrence: T(n) = 2T(n/3)+n^2?

Tags: math, recurrence, equation-solving

Substitution Method and Recursion Tree Method for:

- T(n) = 2/7             If n=1
- T(n) = 2T(n/3)+n^2     Otherwise

How to solve such a system of equations?

Comment: What is your question? And what has this to do with java?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

Answer (score 0):

The equation clearly only can be solved when `n` is a power of 3. Substituting `n` by a new variable `k^3` gives a simpler equation that can be solved by [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), python's symbolic mathematics library:

```py
from sympy import Function, rsolve, S, symbols, Eq

k, n = symbols("k n", integer=True, positive=True)

f = Function('f')
g = Function('g')

# T(n) = 2T(n/3)+n^2    T(1) = 2/7

T = Eq(f(n), 2 * f(n / 3) + n * n)
Tk = T.subs({n: 3 ** k, f(n): g(k), f(n / 3): g(k - 1)})

s = rsolve(Tk, g(k), {g(0): 2 / S(7)})
print("solution for k:", s.cancel())

for k in range(0, 11):
    print(f"k={k}, n={3 ** k}, T(n)={-2 ** k + 3 ** (2 * k + 2) / S(7)}")
```

This results in following formula for `k`: -2<sup>k</sup> + 3<sup>2*k+2</sup>/7

The values for k=0..10 are:

```
k=0, n=1, T(n)=2/7
k=1, n=3, T(n)=67/7
k=2, n=9, T(n)=701/7
k=3, n=27, T(n)=6505/7
k=4, n=81, T(n)=58937/7
k=5, n=243, T(n)=531217/7
k=6, n=729, T(n)=4782521/7
k=7, n=2187, T(n)=43045825/7
k=8, n=6561, T(n)=387418697/7
k=9, n=19683, T(n)=3486780817/7
k=10, n=59049, T(n)=31381052441/7
```

Comment: Was this answer helpful?